# How to merge these url rewrite rules together?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use these 3 rules in .htaccess file to rewrite url and they work well. But i think these 3 rules could be merge together into 1 rule. Could someone tell me how to do it? And a little bit explaination would be appreciated since I am new to the regex:)

```
RewriteRule ^index.htm$       news/index.htm
RewriteRule ^news/$           news/index.htm
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$   news/index_$1.htm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge two of them into a single rule, but the last one needs to be separate:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.htm|news/)$ news/index.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$   news/index_$1.htm [L]
```